# debian: network manager not launched

Tags: xfce, networkmanager

EDIT: I reinstalled debian and xfce and like the other time, at the beginning the network manager was there and I saw my connections etc but after 5min, gone.... but still wifi on.

i.

on my laptop with debian 10 (xfce) I have wifi working but on top right of my desktop, I have an ''X'' on network, and I can't activate network.... it says : network manager is not launched. Anb because of that, I can't see the wifi network available, the wired connection etc

ideas?   we see that the service works but as I said, it says not, and I can do any configuration..
thanks

```
    ~$ systemctl status
● e6530
    State: running
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 0 units
    Since: Fri 2021-01-22 19:47:34 EST; 35min ago
   CGroup: /
           ├─user.slice
           │ └─user-1000.slice
           │   ├─user@1000.service
           │   │ ├─pulseaudio.service
           │   │ │ └─1033 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no
           │   │ ├─gvfs-daemon.service
           │   │ │ ├─1036 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
           │   │ │ └─1110 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.17 /org/gtk/gvf
           │   │ ├─gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service
           │   │ │ └─1090 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
           │   │ ├─xfce4-notifyd.service
           │   │ │ └─1062 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd
           │   │ ├─init.scope
           │   │ │ ├─927 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
           │   │ │ └─928 (sd-pam)
           │   │ ├─gpg-agent.service
           │   │ │ └─1002 /usr/bin/gpg-agent --supervised
lines 1-23
```

Edit : after rebooted, now I'm stucked there , see photo, during 5 min and after instead to open xfce login page,. I am in tty1 session..
?[image]

Comment: To see the status of NetworkManager: `systemctl status NetworkManager`. Right now, though, your PC seems to be trying to start the mail server. Can you press ALT-F2 and log onto the second terminal? If so, use the journal or appropriate logs to find out what causes this.

Comment: hi, Mail server ??  weird.. Im new on linux, could you explain me about how using journal on my terminal?

Comment: here :   `~$ systemctl status NetworkManager
● NetworkManager.service
   Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit NetworkManager.service is masked.) 
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2021-01-22 23:02:02 EST; 1h 6min ago
 Main PID: 629 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 `

Comment: here some logs:

`  Jan 22 22:52:45 e6530 udisksd[622]: udisks daemon version 2.8.1 starting
Jan 22 22:52:45 e6530 udisksd[622]: failed to load module mdraid: libbd_mdraid.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jan 22 22:52:45 e6530 NetworkManager[629]: <info>  [1611373965.9701] NetworkManager (version 1.14.6) is starting... (for the first time)
Jan 22 22:52:45 e6530 NetworkManager[629]: <info>  [1611373965.9702] Read config: /etc/Networonf
/

`

                                       `

Comment: Run `systemctl status` as root to see more information. The journal entries for NetworkManager can be seen like this: `journalctl -u NetworkManager -e` (again, you need to be root). The -e option goes to the last log entry. Better add the output to your question; if you put it in comments, it becomes unreadable.

Comment: I see that NetworkManager is masked. This means it shouldn't get started at all. I would unmask it: `systemctl unmask NetworkManager`.

Comment: I did `systemctl unmask NetworkManager` but after reboot, still no icon. so I can't changed my wifi network or choose wired etc and see SSID etc

Comment: I did that : `sudo apt install network-manager-gnome

From the terminal:

nm-applet &`
and an icon is now on my right corner but still no information about network ssid available